# Overriding IE settings when embedding a WebBrowser control using IE9

Tags: windows, com, internet-explorer-9, webbrowser-control

I have an application (written in C++ with MFC, but I don't think that that's particularly relevant) that embeds the Internet Explorer ActiveX WebBrowser control for the purpose of showing some HTML pages. One requirement has always been to use the application's font name and size settings as the default settings for the HTML, rather than Internet Exporer's defaults.

To achieve this, the application implements the IDocHostUIHandler2 COM interface, which it passes to the WebBrowser control. This causes the control to call the application's implementation of [GetOptionKeyPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753258%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which lets the application set the registry location that the WebBrowser control gets its settings from. Armed with Sysinternals' tools to see which keys IE uses to find the font name and size, this has been sufficient to do what I need.

However, the appeareance of Internet Explorer 9 has come as a nasty surprise: on all machines that I've tested with that have IE9 installed, the WebBrowser control uses its own settings, ignoring the registry location from the application. Testing with a debugger shows that the WebBrowser control never calls the provided GetOptionKeyPath.

A bit more experimentation shows that the IE9 WebBrowser control is calling the similar (but not identical) [GetOverrideKeyPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753274%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method: this allegedly provides a way to override IE settings, while falling back to IE's actual settings if nothing is found in the relevant part of the registry. Unfortunately this has two problems: 1) It's not quite what I want, and 2) IE9 doesn't always check under the GetOverrideKeyPath registry location before going to the IE default registry settings.

Looking at the [GetOptionKeyPath MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753258%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) there are a few complaints along similar lines, but no solutions. Has anyone found a clean way to persuade the WebBrowser control to revert to the pre-IE9 behaviour of actually calling GetOptionKeyPath as documented?

Comment: There was a regression here in IE9. It's something that is currently getting looked at as a part of the servicing (patch) process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've come up with a hack to solve this problem, but I should warn you: it's not pretty. Stop reading now if you've easily offended ...

Since there seems to be no way of making IE9 use the IDocHostUIHandler::GetOptionKeyPath() method, I used SysInternals' tools to see which IE9 DLLs accessed the relevant parts of the registry to load the IE9 settings. This revealed the only culprits as "mshtml.dll" and "iertutil.dll", both of which call RegOpenKeyExW().

The plan was then to load these DLLs before initializing the WebBrowser control, and patch them so that calls are redirected to my code, where I can lie about what registry key I've opened, using dbghelp.dll. So, to start, before initializing the WebBrowser control:

```
if (theApp.GetIEVersion() >= 9.0)
{
  HMODULE advadi = ::LoadLibrary("advapi32.dll");
  HMODULE mshtml = ::LoadLibrary("mshtml.dll");
  HookApiFunction(mshtml,advadi,"advapi32.dll","RegOpenKeyExW",(PROC)HookRegOpenKeyExW);
  HMODULE iertutil = ::LoadLibrary("iertutil.dll");
  HookApiFunction(iertutil,advadi,"advapi32.dll","RegOpenKeyExW",(PROC)HookRegOpenKeyExW);
}
```

And now, the code that does the evil work of scanning the DLLs import address tables, and patching the requested function (error handling omitted to keep the code size down):

```
void HookApiFunction(HMODULE callingDll, HMODULE calledDll, const char* calledDllName, const char* functionName, PROC newFunction)
{
  // Get the pointer to the 'real' function
  PROC realFunction = ::GetProcAddress(calledDll,functionName);

  // Get the import section of the DLL, using dbghelp.dll's ImageDirectoryEntryToData()
  ULONG sz;
  PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR import = (PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR)
    ImageDirectoryEntryToData(callingDll,TRUE,IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT,&sz);

  // Find the import section matching the named DLL
  while (import->Name)
  {
    PSTR dllName = (PSTR)((PBYTE)callingDll + import->Name);
    {
      if (stricmp(dllName,calledDllName) == 0)
       break;
    }
    import++;
  }
  if (import->Name == NULL)
    return;

  // Scan the IAT for this DLL
  PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA thunk = (PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA)((PBYTE)callingDll + import->FirstThunk);
  while (thunk->u1.Function)
  {
    PROC* function = (PROC*)&(thunk->u1.Function);
    if (*function == realFunction)
    {
      // Make the function pointer writable and hook the function
      MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mbi;
      ::VirtualQuery(function,&mbi,sizeof mbi);
      if (::VirtualProtect(mbi.BaseAddress,mbi.RegionSize,PAGE_READWRITE,&mbi.Protect))
      {
        *function = newFunction;
        DWORD protect;
        ::VirtualProtect(mbi.BaseAddress,mbi.RegionSize,mbi.Protect,&protect);
        return;
      }
    }
    thunk++;
  }
```

Finally, the function that I have patched the DLLs to call in my code, in place of RegOpenKeyExW():

```
LONG WINAPI HookRegOpenKeyExW(HKEY hKey, LPCWSTR lpSubKey, DWORD ulOptions, REGSAM samDesired, PHKEY phkResult)
{
  static const wchar_t* ieKey = L"Software\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer";

  // Never redirect any of the FeatureControl settings
  if (wcsstr(lpSubKey,L"FeatureControl") != NULL)
    return ::RegOpenKeyExW(hKey,lpSubKey,ulOptions,samDesired,phkResult);

  if (wcsnicmp(lpSubKey,ieKey,wcslen(ieKey)) == 0)
  {
    // Redirect the IE settings to our registry key
    CStringW newSubKey(m_registryPath);
    newSubKey.Append(lpSubKey+wcslen(ieKey));
    return ::RegOpenKeyExW(hKey,newSubKey,ulOptions,samDesired,phkResult);
 }
 else
   return ::RegOpenKeyExW(hKey,lpSubKey,ulOptions,samDesired,phkResult);
}
```

Amazingly enough, this horrible hack actually works. But please, Microsoft, if you're listening, please fix this properly in IE10.

Comment: Was this fixed in IE 10? Also isn't such dll hook going to raise an alarm in antivirus software? Is this hook attaching to UI thread app owns or entire OS?

Comment: I haven't tried IE10, and I've not seen any anti-virus hits as a result of this technique. It will only affect the current process, since all its doing is patching the IAT in the process space.

Comment: Why aren't you overriding FeatureControl settings? These can mess up your browser control too.

Comment: I tried using something similar on Win8.1/IE11 but I'm getting DLL names like api-ms-win-downlevel-advapi32-l1-1-0.dll instead of advapi32.dll.  I may try to recognize the stub library, but this hack is getting overboard!  Reason for even trying this is can't get `GetOptionKeyPath` to work in this environment either (it is getting called but the reg entries are still coming from the default location for whatever reason).