# Overriding IE rendering mode embedded WebBrowser control

Tags: internet-explorer, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to get a MFC/C++ application on Win8.1/IE11 with an embedded browser window to render in `edge` (most recent standards) mode.  The content for the window is served locally (i.e. not from a web site).

Using `<!DOCTYPE html>` and `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">` (first thing) in the head gets me IE8 rendering (it's IE5 with neither, IE7 with just DOCTYPE).

I'm aware of the registry setting `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer` for adding your own process name to `Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION`... this in fact works and it renders in IE11 with one **major** problem: the application happens to be named *identically* to a Microsoft application which *breaks* when I set that feature!  It seems that the registry setting feature doesn't allow for a full path name to a process either.  I know, rename the process... but I can't easily do that for a variety of historical reasons.  So...

I have extended the handler `class MyDocHandler : public IDocHostUIHandler2, public IOleClientSite {...}` and use it via `pOleObject->SetClientSite( pMyDocHandler );` before any navigation happens.  I implemented `IDocHostUIHandler2::GetOverrideKeyPath` which is called as expected and I return my own application key path (nearly identical to Microsoft's, i.e. `Software\MyCompany\Internet Explorer` instead (also tried just `Software\MyCompany`).  I've put the registry setting in place under that path, e.g. my `Software\MyCompany\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION\MyProcess.exe` but it seems to be ignoring it.  I've tried a few different registry path options as well but I'm out of ideas.  Oh, I also tried without success using `GetOptionKeyPath`.

Additionally I've gone so far as trying the `HookRegOpenKeyExW` hack suggested in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850911/overriding-ie-settings-when-embedding-a-webbrowser-control-using-ie9) but there are now apparently several additional stub library compatibility layers making that even more unwieldy.

Anyone got some insight?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Additionally I've gone so far as trying the HookRegOpenKeyExW hack
>   suggested in another question but there are now apparently several
>   additional stub library compatibility layers making that even more
>   unwieldy.

As an alternative, you may want to try [`RegOverridePredefKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724901%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23073183/1768303).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Too bad there isn't a `RegOverride**Specific**Key` version of that API instead of an entire predefined root key.  I tried it out, it does seem to work, but I'm concerned about a few things... one concern is overriding some other behaviors of IE like download location, custom security settings, etc. IE dumps down a whole set of default registry items into my redirected location.  Another concern is other registry interactions now being redirected (e.g. startup settings, other COM components, etc.). Would hate to have to try to keep entire CURRENT_USER key tree up to date.

Comment: @mark, if you first make a deep copy of the original key to the redirected location, I think you're going to be all right.